# Raster masking with vector error in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, raster, masking

I have a global glc-2000 raster map. I would like to clip it to study specific area. I used boundries of continents shapefile as mask. Both of them have same projection.  Since I am beginner I have followed steps of this tutorial using QGIS 3.6:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

I  hoped that I get Europe output raster layer but the result was a black hole. What went wrong?

[image]